# Ориентация изображения браузером

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

У меня на сайте при клике на превьюшку открывается оригинал изображения. Но, почему-то, фотографии,ориентированные вертикально, отображаются горизонтально.
За счет чего вообще это решается?
CSS, JS или в граф. редакторе как-то задается этот параметр?

Comment: Здравствуйте как минимум надо показать код чтобы увидеть вашу проблему ...

Comment: Да нет никакого кода. <img src=""> и все. Извините, может глупый вопрос. Но я думал, что в самом изображении устройством, на кот. оно снималось, делается отметка о ориентации (горизонтальная или вертикальная), ну и потом можно это менять в различных граф. редакторах.

Comment: @Станислав а можно само изображение получить? только боюсь если Вы его на прямую в вопрос добавите наверняка система его перекрнвертирует. они на мобилу сняты?

Comment: Да, все снимал на iPhone-4. Но понимаете, что интересно... Если я кидаю ссылку на target="_blank", там браузер (у меня Chrome) нормально ее определяет и позиционирует. Т.е. где-то внутри есть отметка. И это не одна фотка. У меня подборка с поездки - около 300 шт и из них штук 20-30 вертикальных. А  я блог взялся делать на Ларе.